# Reference a local HTML file in container-bound project using a Library function

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries

I have a Library of functions that I want to use in a few different Google Forms (it's  a simple set of functions that creates a draft to easily reply to the person who submitted the form). I tested my script in a project outside of the Library and all works as expected, so no problems with the script. However, I want to use various HTML templates for my email messages depending on the form -- i.e. a "Contact Us" form template vs. an "Email List" template. My script references an HTML file which I've named `Draft.html` for easy reference, and **if I have a `Draft.html` file saved to my Library project, it works just fine**. However, I don't want to actually access the file in the Library... **I want to access a file named `Draft.html` in each individual container-bound project**. I've looked around here but can only seem to find help/info regarding how to reference *functions* across Libraries/projects, and no info on how to reference a project's local *file* from within a Library script.

Library function:

```js
function makeDraft(subject, respondent, htmlTemplate) {
  var htmlMessage = createEmailTemplate(respondent, htmlTemplate);
  Logger.log(htmlMessage);

  GmailApp.createDraft(
    respondent.email, // Respondent email
    subject, // Subject
    "", // plaintext body
    {
    htmlBody: htmlMessage
    }
  );
}

function createEmailTemplate(respondent, htmlTemplate) {
  var template = HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile(htmlTemplate);

  template.respondent = respondent;

  var message = template.evaluate().getContent();

  return message;
}
```

Where `subject` is a string, `respondent` is an object containing the respondent's email, Timestamp, message, etc., and `htmlTemplate` is a string which I've set to "Draft" to reference the "Draft.html" file in the container-bound project.

However, like I said, if a file named `Draft.html` exists in the **Library** it accesses it just fine. But, if this file doesn't exist in the Library, it doesn't work, even though I have a file named `Draft.html` saved in the container-bound project. I'm sure this is because I'm executing a Library function, and that function is trying to read files in the Library project. Maybe it's obvious, but this is the error I get if I have **no** `Draft.html` in the Library, but I **do** have a file named `Draft.html` in my container-bound script project:

`Exception: No HTML file named Draft was found.`

So, my main question is, **is it even possible to reference a file in a container-bound script project** from a Library function? I can't find any info in the documentation about this on Google's side, and my situation seems to be a little unique. Since I'm the creator/owner of the Library, I **can** update my code easily enough so that part of the original function references the container-bound script it's executing from rather than the Library itself. I just don't know how to do that.

Container-bound script: (adding per request)

```js
const replySubject = "Re: Contact Us"
const draftTemplate = "Draft";

function testFunction() {
  emailOnFormSubmit(replySubject,draftTemplate);
}

function emailOnFormSubmit(subject,template) {
  return FormAutoEmailLibrary.emailOnFormSubmit(subject,template);
}
```

Example of `respondent` object:

```js
var respondent = {
  email : "example@test.com",
  firstName : "Susan",
  message : "This is an example message."
}
```

HTML example of `Draft.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- style here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>[DRAFT-RESPONSE]</p>
    <h2>Original message from: <?= respondent.email ?>!</h2>
    <p><strong>Name: </strong> <?= respondent.firstName ?></p>
    <p><strong>Message: </strong> <?= respondent.message ?></p>
    <p><em>This message was sent through a form submission.</em></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Can you add your Container - Bound - Script or include a Minimum reproducible sample of it, this way the community will have better insight over your project and help you with this.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I've added my container-bound script per your request, but unfortunately since it's calling a larger function that includes this smaller script from the Library, it's hard for me to get all the working parts up here properly for a reproducible example without just posting the whole script. But I added an example of a "respondent" object and the "Draft.html" code to give a better example of how I'm replacing some text, creating an html template, and then just dropping the html into the script. My issue is when trying to access the file with the templated HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current situation, how about the following modification?

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, under the Google Apps Script project (client side) including a library (library side), when the HTML filename is used on the client side by `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile`, it seems that the HTML file in the client side is used. By this, when the HTML filename is used on the library side by `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile`, the HTML filename is searched from the Google Apps Script project in the library. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

In order to avoid this issue, how about giving the object of `HtmlService.HtmlTemplate` instead of the filename of the string type? I thought that by this modification, your script might work. When this modification is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Library side:

```js
function makeDraft(subject, respondent, htmlTemplate) {
  var htmlMessage = createEmailTemplate(respondent, htmlTemplate);
  Logger.log(htmlMessage);
  GmailApp.createDraft(
    respondent.email, // Respondent email
    subject, // Subject
    "", // plaintext body
    {
      htmlBody: htmlMessage
    }
  );
}

function createEmailTemplate(respondent, template) {
  template.respondent = respondent;
  var message = template.evaluate().getContent();
  return message;
}
```

#### Client side:

Unfortunately, in your question, I cannot see the script of the client side. So, here, I would like to propose a sample script for using this modification.

In this sample, the identification of the installed library is supposed as `Library`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const subject = "###"; // Please set your value.
  const respondent = {,,,}; // Please set your value.
  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Draft");

  Library.makeDraft(subject, respondent, htmlTemplate);
}
```

- By this modification, the object of `HtmlService.HtmlTemplate` is given to the library side using `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Draft")` at the client side. So, I thought that the script worked.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I didn't have my client-side code in my post before -- I just edited it and tried to add more details for reference. But I think I understand... I'll try to make this kind of change to my script. It seems like this method should work, I'll just need to modify my script on the client-side a bit.

Comment: @Corinne Jacobo Thank you for replying. About `I'll just need to modify my script on the client-side a bit.`, in my proposal, it is required to also modify your library script a little for using `HtmlService.HtmlTemplate` object given from the client side. Please be careful about this. And, for example, if you want to use the argument as the string, you can also do it by `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Draft").getRawContent()`. If my workaround was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Just to update: This works perfectly! I hadn't considered passing the whole template through to the Library function, rather than just the filename, but it works exactly how I need it to. I need to work out a few other things in my code now since I'm structuring it a little differently, but this part at least is working, and that's what I was stuck on. I think this will also help me out with other issues, since the concept can apply to a lot of other problems I've hit in the past. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.